# how to prevent horizontal scroll on css zoom animation

Tags: javascript, html, zooming, css-animations

I want to use a landscape image, that zooms in to the landmark in the center and stays there. 
I have one main issue with the current code I have..

That is the horizontal bar that turns up on zoom.

I want the image to have 100% width but the height to be about 80%

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>



<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/home1.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<a href="#">
    <img src="images/zoom.jpg" alt="">
</a>

</div><!--wrapper-->



</body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
a {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;

}


a img {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;

    float: left;
    margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}
a img:hover {
    opacity: .7;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.05,2.07);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(2.05,2.07);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;


}
```

I am also wondering if there is a way I can make it stay on zoomed in state once the hover is done, so that another element can appear at that point but the zoom is closer.

http://jsfiddle.net/itsnamitashetty/U4HTu/

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:block;` to `a` css. It'll solve your issue.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/U4HTu/1/

```
a {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```